# Perl - How to request HTTPS website

Tags: perl, ssl, https, get, lwp-useragent

I am trying to access a HTTPS website, but it gives me error. I tried with this scripts:

Script 1:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $B = new LWP::UserAgent (agent => 'Mozilla/5.0', cookie_jar =>{});

my $GET = $B->get('https://moz.com')->content;
print $GET;
```

Script 2:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Mozilla::CA;

my $B = new LWP::UserAgent (agent => 'Mozilla/5.0', cookie_jar =>{});
$B->ssl_opts( SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file() );
$B->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 1 );

my $GET = $B->get('https://moz.com')->content;
print $GET;
```

I get this error with both:

```
Can't connect to moz.com:443

LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0) at C:/Perl/site/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 47.
```

I'm using **ActivePerl 5.16.1 Build 1601** on **Windows 7 Ultimate**.

Any idea how to access a HTTPS website using Perl?

Comment: A badly installed module? Your code works like a charm for me. So it's related to your own settings. I'd try first by reinstalling the module, then checking whether querying https is allowed from the machine where the script is ran.

Comment: Which code? Script 1 or Script 2?

Comment: @DavidVerdin 
I reinstalled ActivePerl and now the script is working fine. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I supposed it was something like this; I'll just post my comment as an answer to close the subject.

Answer (score 2):

https calls will fail if you do not have the LWP::Protocol::https module installed.